# cmake : add_library cannot create target "cxx" because another target with the same name already exists

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm using a project which has the following dependencies:

### grpc

- googletest
- benchmark

At the same time my project has benchmarks.

When I declare the following dependencies using `FetchContent` I get following error:

```
add_library cannot create target "benchmark" because another target
  with the same name already exists.  The existing target is an executable
  created in source directory
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(dahj)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
        grpc
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/grpc/grpc.git
        GIT_TAG v1.17.2
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(grpc)

FetchContent_Declare(
        benchmark
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/benchmark.git
        GIT_TAG v1.5.0
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(benchmark)

add_executable(dahj main.cpp grpc++)
```

I know that I can use benchmark without fetching it but by just linking it. But if `grpc` decides to take off benchmark as a dependency it screws my build. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Call `FetchContent_Declare` and `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` for `benchmark` only when there is no "benchmark" target created yet:

```
if (NOT TARGET benchmark)
    FetchContent_Declare(
            benchmark
            GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/benchmark.git
            GIT_TAG v1.5.0
    )
    FetchContent_MakeAvailable(benchmark)
endif()
```

This will safely prevent `benchmark` project to be included twice.

See also that question: [CMake : multiple subprojects using the same static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439631/cmake-multiple-subprojects-using-the-same-static-library)